# How to show alert dialog box if page is switched in bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog, bottom-navigation-bar

Currently I am working on flutter project in which I have used bottom navigation bar and in one of the pages I have a form in which information needs to fill. In this case if the user switches to another page after filling  information and does not submit it, I want to show dialog box to user that "You have information filled leaving this page will discard the info". Please help.

I have tried WillPopScope widget but it only works when you press back button I want to show dialog box when the text fields are filled but not submitted and without submitting user tries to switch to another page.

Comment: Can you attach some code and images for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

In the **onTap** callback, check if the Navbar Item index is not equal to the Item which contains the form. If it is different, show the dialog and await its response.

```
  void _onItemTapped(int index) async {
   if(_selectedIndex == formItemIndex && index != formItemIndex)
    {
       // await showDialog();
    }
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      )
```

Comment: I tried this but dialog box can be seen on every page change.

Comment: I have updated the code. Just another simple check

Comment: Can you help me with how can I call the controllers from different class. As I want to show this dialog only when user has filled the info and not submitted. Thanks.

Comment: You can access controllers either by making the public which is not a good approach. Or you can use any state management technique to place your controllers inside of it.

Comment: Can I use GetX for this ??

Comment: You can use any approach. The idea behind this is to access controllers.